# How to perform a segue in the background when RideRequestButton is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I'm using the Uber SDK for iOS and more specifically a RideRequestWidget to allow my users to call an uber. I'm curious is if there is any way you could perform a segue in the background when the RideRequestButton is pressed.

ex: I have the RideRequestButton on one view controller and when my users are done with Uber and have arrived they need to be directed back to a different view controller than where they started. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this or a different way to do it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, when the user dismisses the Ride Request Widget, you want to take them to a different screen from where they launched it?

I see 2 options to achieve this:

1) In the view controller where you have the button, conform to the `ModalViewControllerDelegate` protocol. When creating your `RideRequestButton` with the `RideRequestViewRequestingBehavior`, set your view controller as the delegate of `rideRequestViewRequestingBehaviorObject.modalRideRequestViewController`, so when the user dismisses the Ride Request Widget, the `modalViewControllerDidDismiss` delegate method will be called and you can do your custom segue at that point.

2) You can create your own custom view controller that contains a `RideRequestView` where you can provide your controls for allowing the user to dismiss the view controller. That way you have control over where you go next. You could still use the `RideRequestButton`, you just need to make a custom class that conforms to the `RideRequesting` protocol and you can initialize the `RideRequestButton` with it. If you follow this approach, you will need to handle login separately, as the `RideRequestView` doesn't handle that for you (it is handled by the `RideRequestViewController`)

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the response! I'm having a slight problem with the first method. My view controller is conforming to the ModalViewControllerDelegate, set my rideRequestViewRequestingBehaviorObject.modalRideRequestViewController, and inserted the modalViewControllerDidDismiss function but when I run the app the modalViewControllerDidDismiss is never called. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: It's hard to debug without seeing your code. Are you sure you set the delegate?